# Can I use filters to annotate matches in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When I do a search on Elasticsearch, I want to have a filter that can indicate which of the results matched the filter and which ones didn't.

Is there a way to use a filter (or something that works similarly) that doesn't filter, but instead reports?

I use a pretty complex filter to remove results, but I would rather have the filtered results differentiated from ones that didn't match the filter. I could do it with multiple queries, but that seems wasteful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [named queries and filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) what you want?

I can interpret your need in a few ways, so I'm not entirely sure. Maybe you could have a tautology filter with named sub-filters.

Comment: Yes. This is precisely what I was looking for.